# Reasoning pseudo force due to accelerating car mathematically

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, relative-motion

For a person inside an acceleration car, his acceleration inside the frame is $a_{\text{rev}}$ , outside the car is accelerating at $a_{\text{car}}$ and person inside is accelerating at a rate of $a_{\text{person}}$

$$a_{\text{rev}} = a_{\text{person}} - a_{\text{car}}$$

Inside the frame the relative acceleration of person seems to be $0$, and so,

$$a_{\text{person}} = a_{\text{car}}$$

Where did the minus sign go? Shouldn't the person be pushed backwards when the car is accelerating forward?

Comment: Who said the negative sign goes away? Is that a typo, or did you do it?

Comment: This my own analysis. But I have read on articles online that it is pseudo force which pushes u back of car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the car the person is pushed backwards with respect to the car precisely because the person's acceleration is less than the car's (initially) .

If you include this in your first equation, you get that the person moves backwards with respect to the car ( again only initially) . This is intuitive as well , we often feel getting pushed back in our seats when the car starts .

Looking at the system from the ground frame ,

The actual forces which accelerate the person are the reaction forces from the seat ,which after an initial moment, make the person's acceleration same as the car .

I will convey my point through an example

Assume you are sitting with your back straight. Your back is not in contact with the seat . And now you press the accelerator on the car. The car accelerates, but the only force to accelerate you forward is the friction from the seat ; which is not enough to accelerate you at the same rate as the car.

Hence your acceleration is less than the car and relative to the car you move back . Now when your back hits the seat , another force comes in ; the normal force on your back.
This provides the additional force required to move at the same acceleration as the car.

At this instant , your acceleration with respect to the car becomes zero and you no longer move backwards .

You can analyze this situation from the car frame as well.

As the accelerations of the car and the man in the ground frame are different initially, a pseudo force is applied on the man in the backward direction. This pulls the man backwards until his back touches the seat which provides the reaction force (or the normal force)  to counter the pseudo force. Thus ,  the man comes to rest in the car frame

Comment: How does buckling relate to how fast the acceleration is changing?

Comment: I have edited my answer. My earlier answer was a bit off the point